C++ SDL2 Как инициализировать SDL в отдельном от основного потоке?
У меня возникла такая проблема: SDL2 отказывается работать вообще при вызове функций в другом потоке(не основном). Я делаю следующее:
void ThreadLoop()
{
    SDL_Window* win;
    SDL_Renderer* ren;
    std::cout<<"Step1"<<std::endl;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVENTS|SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_TIMER);
    std::cout<<"Step2"<<SDL_GetError()<<std::endl;
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(...some settings...);
    
    while(true)
    {
    ...Check events in poll, SDL_RenderPresent and etc...
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char* arv[])
{
std::thread loop(&ThreadLoop);
sleep(100);
std::cout<<"Main ended!"<<std::endl;
return 0;
}

И когда доходит до вызова SDL_Init() не происходит ничего, т.е. ни сама SDL_Init ошибки не дает, ни выполнение дальше не идет(не выводится Step2). Но после вывода Step1 выводится Main ended!
Насколько я знаю, SDL не дружит с вызовом рендеринга окон из потока, не создавшего их, но тут все идет в потоке,в котором и SDL_Init и все остальное вызвано.

Как минимум в macOS это обязан быть только основной поток и больше никакой другой, так что я рекомендовал бы вам даже не пытаться

@andreymal т.е. ни инициализация SDL, ни создание окна, ни его рендеринг не должны быть ни в каком другом потоке,кроме как в самом первом(основном)?

Тут на самом деле целая куча проблем. Во-первых SDL производит кое-какую инициализацию еще до вашей main, так что если хотите что-то инициализировать, то придется самостоятельно предоставлять точку входа на всех поддерживаемых платформах и вручную вызывать там код инициализации SDL. Во-вторых создавать окно стоит (или придется) в основном потоке. В-третьих, для отрисовки в фоновом потоке окно и рендерер необходимо создавать раздельно и все равно придется обходить многие вызовы SDL.
